# Gradle sync error using Navigation Component in base module

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

Using Navigation component alpha09 and have added `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"` to top of base module `build.gradle` but getting following error when doing gradle sync.  I'm using Android Studio 3.4 Canary 9 (but also had same problem using 3.3 RC3)

It looks like a related fix was included in alpha09 - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119662045

```
Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type org.gradle.api.resources.TextResource
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.SafeArgsPlugin.setApplicationId(SafeArgsPlugin.kt:87)
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.SafeArgsPlugin.access$setApplicationId(SafeArgsPlugin.kt:39)
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.SafeArgsPlugin$apply$1$task$1.execute(SafeArgsPlugin.kt:63)
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.SafeArgsPlugin$apply$1$task$1.execute(SafeArgsPlugin.kt:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:360)
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.SafeArgsPlugin$apply$1.invoke(SafeArgsPlugin.kt:59)
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.SafeArgsPlugin$apply$1.invoke(SafeArgsPlugin.kt:39)
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.SafeArgsPluginKt$sam$org_gradle_api_Action$0.execute(SafeArgsPlugin.kt)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:225)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:247)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:236)
    at com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.addVariant(LibraryExtension.java:93)
    at com.android.build.gradle.FeatureExtension.addVariant(FeatureExtension.java:121)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApiObjectFactory.create(ApiObjectFactory.java:134)
```

Comment: There's another issue in Google issue tracker, related to this stacktrace: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121304903

Comment: Updating navigation to 1.0.0-beta01 fixed this issue for me. It was the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just updated to alpha11 and not seeing this issue any more. (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#1.0.0-alpha11)

**UPDATE**
From comments below it looks like alpha11 didn't resolve issue for some people but beta1 did

Comment: Unfortunately the bug is still there in `alpha11`. At the moment the safe args library can not be used in a feature module.

Comment: hmm, not sure why it seems ok for me now....I'll double check in case anything else changed in project (I've marked answer as not accepted in meantime)

Comment: @ulcica what version of Android Studio and also gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using `Android Studio 3.3`, `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0`, `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20`. I think the problem is related to `applicationId` that can not be defined in feature modules. Because it works fine in the app module that has the applicationId.

Comment: For me updating to Alpha11 didn't solve the issue, but updating to Beta01 released this week did the trick.

Comment: anyone getting this problem with navigation 2.0.0 ?